# How to assign value to a Global Variable for global use

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a string `Application.hWndAccessApp` that appears in multiple lines of code to call a custom `MsgBoxT`. Instead of writing `Application.hWndAccessApp` at every instance across modules and classes, I would like it to be assigned to a public variable such as `hid as string`. I know about declaring a public variable and then assigning it a value within a function or SubRoutine.

Here, I would like that value to be assigned globally so that it becomes available across all modules/classes every time I want to use `MsgBoxT` function.

EDIT: I followed the tip from comments below but it gives `Error # 13: Type Mismatch`.

```
Global Const hid = "Application.hWndAccessApp"
```

Then I call it using function below:

```
MsgBoxT hid, "Record Updated!", "Confirmation", VbInformation, 0 , 1000
```

My MsgBoxT function is declared publicy:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function MsgBoxT _
Lib "user32" _
Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
   ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
   ByVal lpText As String, _
   ByVal lpCaption As String, _
   ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
   ByVal wLange As Long, _
   ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
As Long
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the updated question, the variable is a `LongPtr`. Since it's initialized on `Runtime` you have one option:

1. Declaring a **Global LongPtr** that you will assign in a second moment:

   `Global hid As LongPtr` 
   `hid = Application.hWnd`

With the updated code from the question below, it's now running smoothly:

```
Global hid As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function MsgBoxT _
Lib "user32" _
Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
   ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
   ByVal lpText As String, _
   ByVal lpCaption As String, _
   ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
   ByVal wLange As Long, _
   ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
As Long
```

With these changes, it works (tested on my PC):

```
'On This_Workbook
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    hid = Application.hwnd
End Sub

'Anywhere in the code
Sub test()
    MsgBoxT hid, "Record Updated!", "Confirmation", vbInformation, 0, 1000
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It means it's not a `String`. Just change `String` with the actual type it uses. To find out you can use VBA `Debug tools`.

Comment: I updated my Question with the `Code`. Can you please take a look and let me know where I am making a mistake here.

Comment: I have copied and pasted exact words of your `code` and it gives me the same error. It becomes a mystery to me.

Comment: Try now. I found that `Application.hWnd` is working, while `Application.hWndAccessApp` is not. Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: @Lone The last part of the code should be wrapped in a `Sub`. Check the updated code.

Comment: Yes, I had wrapped it correctly. Interestingly, for me `Application.hWnd` gives error but `Application.hWndAccessApp` works fine. While it works this way but it is not want I had set out to resolve since now I have to assign `hid = Application.hWndAccessApp` every time I would like to call `MsgBoxT` which is bit more characters than in original case. Could you please think of a way to make `Application.hWndAccessApp` part of `MsgBoxT function` so that I don't have to worry about this part and can simply live off `MsgBoxT` alone?

Comment: Sure, just put `hid = Application.hWndAccessApp` into `Workbook_Open` or anywhere it's executed only one time. I initialized it in `Sub Test` only to show an example, but you actually need to initialize `hid` only one time, because it's `Global`.

Comment: Alright, sounds a fair idea. Can you tell if the variable will variable will retain the value once I close the form that initiated it?

Comment: Yes, if the variable it's `Global` it will retain the value. If you want to test it, just use `Debug.Print hit` in different part of the code and it will print on console the value of the variable. If this was helpful, please upvote/accept the answer, so others can benefit from it. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, I did. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you need further assistance with your code, just post another question and we'll happily help. Ps: Thanks for the upvote, also remember to accept the answer! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191323/discussion-between-lone-and-louis).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't online and I couldn't join the chat. To accept an answer, take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
Public hid as string

Sub Main()
    hid = Application.hWndAccessApp
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   hid = Application.hWndAccessApp

End Sub
```